# Access MYSQL from my Instance Application but Local is working

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2

I am running a PHP application here http://www.france-hotel.com
I am able to run some PHP script from my computer to access a MYSQL database
I have setup a security group to allow access to port 3306 so from my local computer it is working, I can access my mysql database. 
When i do the same thing on my website, i dont have any answer and I cant view any error message, the page is blanked.
My program stop just after the command

`$base = mysql_connect ($DB_SERVER, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);`

The only thing is see is coming from my application dashboard showing this message :

> Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Warning. 100.0 % of the
>   requests are failing with HTTP 5xx.

do you have any idea or experience about this problem ?
L

Comment: First step; enable errors to see what the issue is use; error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1); then you  should have a bit more information to work with

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: What version of PHP is running on your website?

Comment: Also Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)